# NSArray as Private data in Class?

Tags: objective-c, class, object, nsarray

I recently started learning Objective-C. I decided to make a class called "Student" with the properties age, name, and importantly, classes. I have put the classes in an NSArray full of NSStrings. My issue is, if I define it as an @property, it automatically creates a setter and getter method for it. I dont want that in my class. How do I define an NSArray as private data in the class, without allowing for the setter and getter?

Here's the header code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Student : NSObject

@property NSString * Name;
@property unsigned short age;
@property BOOL isFullTime;
@property NSMutableArray * Classes;

@end
```

[NSGreeter ThanksGuys];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few popular options. Of course, you can substitute types as you wish:

**A:**

Place it in the header, and specify `@private` access.

```
// Student.h
@interface Student : NSObject
{
@private // << note: protected is the default when declared in this scope.
   NSArray * ivar;
}
@end
```

**B:**

Place it in the @implementation block. you could specify access, but that is not usually an issue because it is not visible to any other translation.

```
// Student.m
@implementation Student
{
@private // << note: private is the default when declared in this scope.
   NSArray * ivar;
}
@end
```

**C:**

Declare it in the class continuation:

```
// Student.m
@interface Student ()
{
  NSArray * ivar;
}

@end
```

**D:**

Declare as a property in the class continuation:

```
// Student.m
@interface Student ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * ivar;

@end
```

Comment: Strictly, `@private` is unecessary (except as a reminder) for an ivar declared in `@implementation` -- that's the default (and other visibility specifiers don't really work).

Comment: @W'rkncacnter ah, cool - i did not know that. i have maintained gcc compat in many cases, so i have not used that feature much. other visibility specifiers do work as expected (of course if visible in the translation). cheers.

Comment: @Justin and @ (everyone else too) Thanks! I chose option A. Is there any reason `@private` has to be in brackets and `@property` comes after?

Comment: @redIago you're welcome. well, a property is perfectly capable of declaring an ivar. if you don't want generated methods which the property brings, then declare the ivar in the braces. if you *do* want the accessors provided by a property, then declaring it within braces would be redundant. b) historical reasons, i assume. "Option A" was the only place until a few years ago.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter: No, the default is `@protected`. And all the visibility specifiers *do* work. e.g. you can make an instance variable `@public`, and you can indeed access it from any class without a warning (just that most people don't realize the syntax for accessing an instance variable of an object is `->`)

Comment: @newacct the defaults are `@protected` in `@interface` declarations, `@private` in class continuations, and `@private` in `@implementation`s  (at least, according to the version of clang i tested with).

Comment: @Justin: Yes, "of course if visible in the translation" is the key, though I seem to remember testing accessing a `@protected` `@implementation`-declared ivar in a subclass and not being successful.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter you may be remembering correctly. the compiler's certainly evolving quickly. fwiw, it does work as it should with the compiler version i tested with; subclasses do have access to protected ivars declared in `@implementation TYPE {}` scopes today.

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface Student : NSObject {

    @private
    NSMutableArray * Classes;

}

@property NSString * Name;
@property unsigned short age;
@property BOOL isFullTime;

@end
```

Comment: Hi, its wrong, by default all the member variables in objc is protected not private. So you need to use the keyword @private

Comment: Gosh. I missed he wanted it private. I just noticed he did not want the accessors. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is, `@private` doesn't mean exactly the same as it does in other languages -- its primary difference from `@protected` (the default) is w/r/t inheritance. A "private" ivar is inaccessible even to subclasses. A "protected" variable is accessible to any class from here down on the inheritance tree. "Protected" is almost always what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyword @private

```
@interface Student : NSObject
{
    @private
    NSMutableArray * Classes;
}

@property NSString * Name;
@property unsigned short age;
@property BOOL isFullTime;

@end
```